# Jump to definition not working with Rac4

Tags: xcode, frameworks, reactive-cocoa

I'm using XCode Version 7.0.1 (7A1001)
Carthage version 0.8.0
to checkout: "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" "swift2" branch.

I'm not sure why Xcode can't "Jump to definition" of swift code from ReactiveCocoa any more.

I find that it makes it very hard to have to keep going to ReactiveCocoa xocde project to checkout functions and code signatures.

If anyone had this issue i would appreciate a solution.

Comment: I think it's an Xcode bug. The Swift compiler is not very stable, often crashes.